# Unable to extract value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to calculate when there is a change in one of the 3 input boxes and then display that answer. I'm able to trigger the function when there's a change but I'm unable to get the values from each of the inputs. Below are html and js snippets.

```
HTML:
    <div>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Base</th>
                    <th class="gen-specific g3 g4 g5 g6">IVs</th>
                    <th class="gen-specific g3 g4 g5 g6">EVs</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hp" onchange="hp_calculator()">
                    <td>
                        <label>HP</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="base" value="100" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="gen-specific g3 g4 g5 g6">
                        <input class="ivs calc-trigger" value="31" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="gen-specific g3 g4 g5 g6">
                        <input class="evs calc-trigger" type="number" min="0" max="252" step="4" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td><span class="total">341</span>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function hp_calculator() {  
    var hp = $(this).find(".base").val()*$(this).find(".iv calc-trigger").val()+$(this).find(".ev calc-trigger").val();

    $(this).find(".total").val(hp);
}
```

Comment: I see a "expected expression, got '*' " error in my console when running your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `this` is going to be the window and not the element. Pass the element inside your handler instead and use the parameter.

```
<tr class="hp" onchange="hp_calculator(this)">
```

Then you need to change your class selectors`.class1.class2` for a many class selector, and then `.text()` to change the text of the `span` element. A final note is you left off the `"s"` in both `ivs` and `evs`:

```
function hp_calculator(ele) {  
    var hp = $(ele).find(".base").val()*$(ele).find(".ivs.calc-trigger").val()+$(ele).find(".evs.calc-trigger").val();

    $(ele).find(".total").text(hp);
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mqc352e8/)

---

*Note*

It's generally bad practice to give event handlers inline. Rather I would recommend you to attach them directly in JavaScript, this way `this` will work as you would expect. Here is an example how you would do so in jQuery ([*demo*](https://jsfiddle.net/mqc352e8/1/)):

```
$('.hp').change(function(){
    var hp = $(this).find(".base").val()*$(this).find(".ivs.calc-trigger").val()+$(this).find(".evs.calc-trigger").val();

    $(this).find(".total").text(hp);
});
```

Comment: I have multiple classes calling that same function though. I just thought this was the best way around that. What would the best practice be in this case?

Comment: @chiangy77 If you only want a single element calling this you could use something like  `id="hp"` instead and change the handler to `$('#hp').change(...)`.